# Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62) while cross-compiling from linux to openwrt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Trying to execute "make". I have checked the toolchain directory, which is fine as I have tried successfully compiled some other files. Want to know the reason behind this error, and where to check for solution.

```
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz  7246 Dec 17 23:33 csi_fun.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz  2133 Dec 17 23:33 csi_fun.h
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz  4488 Dec 17 23:33 csi_fun.o
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz  3881 Dec 17 23:33 main.c
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz  4024 Dec 17 23:33 main.o
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz   399 Dec 22 15:46 Makefile
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ayaz ayaz 13580 Dec 17 23:33 recv_csi


ayaz@ubuntu:~/Atheros_CSI_tool_OpenWRT_UserSpaceApp_src-master/recvCSI$ make
mips-openwrt-linux-gcc csi_fun.o main.o -o recvCSI
/home/ayaz/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.16/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: csi_fun.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/home/ayaz/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.16/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: csi_fun.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
csi_fun.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [recvCSI] Error 1
```

Comment: errr have you tried to run make clean before running make? looks like a library clash of some sort.

Comment: Yes, I have tried "make clean" same result

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED after re-installing the toolchain directiry

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled an object for your host system instead of your target system (i.e forgot to specify `ARCH` or `CROSS_COMPILER`) you will need to delete those objects. `make clean` or `make distclean` usually does the trick.